# Что означает IP-адрес в сервисе "узнать свой IP"?

Tags: сеть, ip, маршрутизация

Проверял ip адрес по сервису узнать ip и в настройках роутера. Совершенно разные цифры. Например узнать свой ip (цифры немного изменены): 46.39.43.2. А в настройках роутера Адрес IPv4 10.5.23.64  Маска подсети   255.255.255.0.

> 1) Почему разные значения в настройках роутера и через сервис "узнать
>   свой ip"?
>   2) В настройках сетевого подключения windows ipv4
>   192.168.1.56 и dns-серверы ipv4 192.168.1.1  - тут вроде понятно, это локальный ip сети. Только вопрос, этот локальный кто устанавливает,
>   роутер автоматически?
>   3) Правда, что интернет на стандартных тарифах
>   динамический (провайдер акадо)? Если это так, то почему каждый раз при
>   проверке в сервисе "узнать мой ip" показывается один и тот же ip
>   адрес?

Comment: `по сервису узнать ip` внешний IP , который выдаёт провайдер из списка своих IP . 10.5.23.64 - это внутренний IP в сети провайдера, ни на что не влияет.

Comment: `динамический` - это значит провайдер вправе менять IP когда хочет, а статический - не в праве. Поэтому динамический IP не значит, что он будет меняться. А вообще вы с форумом ошиблись

Comment: внешний ip 46.39.43.2 - это ip, который выдает провайдер на одну  квартиру или еще у тысячи квартир такой же ip?

Comment: `46.39.43.2` конечно может быть у многих один IP . Только если вы не купите себе выделенный IP - как например при покупке хостинга.

Comment: Т.е. грубо говоря при другом внешним ip (у того же или другого провайдера) у кого-то из пользователей может быть такой же 10.5.23.64 внутренний ip?

Comment: Совершенно верно, определятся какой пакет, какому пользователю, на сетевом уровне сети, будет с помощью маски подсети.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш провайдер по умолчанию не даёт публичных IP адресов. [Их можно получить за отдельную плату по запросу.](http://www.akado.ru/sub/faq/?category_id=2473)

> На один компьютер, зарегистрированный в Сети «АКАДО», выдается один IP-адрес. По умолчанию компьютер получает внутренний (private) IP-адрес. Внешний адрес может быть выделен по заявлению абонента.

Вследствие такой схемы вы и другие клиенты Акадо выходите с одного внешнего IP адреса.

Comment: Т.е. все внутренние IP, которые выдает "Акадо" на один компьютер уникальны? И в сети Акадо не может быть еще одного 10.5.23.64, верно? Но в сети какого-нибудь другого провайдера вполне может быть 10.5.23.64, правильно? А внешний IP - этот тот, которых ограниченное количество на весь мир, правильно?

Comment: В сети другого может быть. Внешних мало, да.